# why anuglar routing not working for 4 pages

Tags: angular

I have created 4 components: home, about, product, contact. I wanted to navigate between them. But I am unable to use routing to do this. After searching StackOverflow, I found that I have to add this in HTML for `routerlink`: `routerLink="[/abouts]"`. But then also it not working. I have added the error log below and my component and router code.

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a routerLink="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="[/about]">abouts us</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="[/products]">produts</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="[/contacts]">contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutsComponent } from './abouts/abouts.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './product/product.component';
import { ContactUsComponent } from './contact-us/contact-us.component'
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes:Routes=[
  {path:'', component : HomeComponent},
  {path:'about', component : AboutsComponent},
  {path:'contacts', component : ContactUsComponent},
  {path:'products', component : ProductComponent},
  {path:'about', component : AboutsComponent}
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutsComponent,
    ProductComponent,
    ContactUsComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)


  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '%5B/about%5D'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '%5B/about%5D'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:4295)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:4259)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:29)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:56)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:469)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1603)
```

Comment: You haven't configured a route named `abouts`, you only have `about`, twice.

Comment: changes are made as per your suggestion.  But then also not worked.  the update code I have posted. please look through it and give me suggestion

Comment: `[routerLink]="['/about']"`

Answer (score 0):

`[routerLink]="['/about']"`

Your want to pass an array of string as a value.

Since you're not passing a basic string but an array, you need to put the routerLink directive within brackets

Also your url part needs to be within single quotes. Since strings are delimited with single quotes.

Comment: Valid to remove the array as well.